# Centering text vertically in Firefox. Chrome and others look fine

Tags: html, css, firefox

How do I center the words 'GUNS N ROSES' in the css below. I've tried everything I know this far. It works ok in Chrome and Safari, but fails in Firefox and Opera.

Note the images below. The text in Firefox appears higher up.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> New Document </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://onr.com/css/fonts.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://onr.com/css/nav.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>

<body>

<header>

<div class="cont">

    <div class="logo">
        <span>GUNS 'N' ROSES</span>
    </div>

    <div class="me">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Sign In</a></li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li><a href="/">Sign Up</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    color: #333333;
    font-family: "proxima-nova",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.cont{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #34495E;
    height:50px;
}

.me {
    float:right;
}

.me ul {
    float:right;
    list-style: none outside none;
}

.me li  {
    float:left;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.me li  a{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    text-decoration:none;
}

.me li  a:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
}

.logo{
color: #FFFFFF; 
     font-family: 'Bebas',sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 300;
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
}

.logo span{
    height:50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    line-height:0;

}

.logo img {
 margin: auto ;
}
```

[image: FireFox]
[image]

Comment: its probably because Chrome and Safari use `Webkit` as the rendering engine. so these rules are set by the browser by default `-webkit-margin-before: 1em;-webkit-margin-after: 1em;-webkit-padding-start: 40px;` if you set `.me ul { -webkit-margin-before: 0em;-webkit-margin-after: 0em; -webkit-padding-start: 0px;}` then you should probably see the same output in Chrome and Safari

Comment: By adding `line-height:50px` on class `.logo span` works for you?

Comment: Typically, you're better off using padding to get your extra height, rather than setting the height directly if you want to have centered content because it works in every browser.

Comment: @david No luck with all that. It's the font I'm guessing, that's causing all these problems.

Comment: @anurupr and Kheema Pandy No. Does not work.

Comment: could you post a jsfiddle with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Style the span as "display:inline-block;" and give "line-height:XX px;" it will work.

Answer (score 0):

if you reset some defaut margin (`ul`) and give only a line-height to `ul` and `span`,  it will gives these element their height and will center any text in it. as long as it stands one 1 line See : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BmFID/ .

```
.logo span, .me ul {
  margin:0;
  line-height:50px;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px ; /* demo purpose, to be removed */
}
```

original `.logo span` rules  removed .

Comment: You can even just set `line-height` on `.cont` and reset `margin` to `ul` : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zhyrm/